# ncat command gives Idle timeout expired on using option "-i"

Tags: netcat, nc

I am using the `nc` command to upload a file to a device, this is how I am using it:

`nc -i1 "device ip" "port" < /path/to/file`

this command works fine on Scientific Linux 6.4 32-bit, but after upgrading to CentOS 7.4 64-bit, the command returns

`Ncat: Idle timeout expired (1000 ms)`

I realized there is a bugzilla item on RedHat website [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1206652), they are saying that `nc` is being replaced by `ncat` and it did not work. I even tried `cat` the file then pipe it to `nc` or `ncat` and it did not work. Any tips on resolving this issue?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the time out?

Comment: Yes, 10 seconds and it did not work.

Comment: Try using the verbosity flags.

Comment: It just shows the version and connected, then the same error message

Comment: If you are just worried about the connection getting stuck, you could prefix the command with `timeout 99` to get the process killed after 99 seconds. Or you could try the socat command which has a possible working `-T` option for idle timeout: `socat -T 1 - TCP:ipaddress:port <file`

Comment: IThe connection works fine on 32 bit system. I'm not sure why it stuck on a 64 bit system

Answer (score 4):

The problem most surely is the `-i` option. At least three different versions of `nc` do exist. [`openbsd-netcat`](http://man.openbsd.org/nc), [`gnu-netcat`](https://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-3-man/netcat) and [`nmap-ncat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ncat.1.html).

You probably switched from one of the `nc` versions where `-i` option means buffer interval to the `nmap` one where `-i` means timeout. So either drop the `-i` option or replace it by `-d`.

Below I've put together manual lines for the `-i` option of each `nc` version mentioned. I also included `-d` for the `nmap` version.

OpenBSD:

```
-i interval        Specifies a delay time interval between lines of text sent and received. Also causes a delay time between connections to multiple ports.
```

GNU:

```
-i SECS
--interval SECS    sets the buffering output delay time. This affects all the current modes and makes the connection sock to buffer outgoing data. This means that in tunnel mode everything received from the listening socket is buffered for the connect socket.
```

NMAP:

```
-i, --idle-timeout <time>  Idle read/write timeout

-d time, --delay time (Specify line delay)
       Set the delay interval for lines sent. This effectively limits
       the number of lines that Ncat will send in the specified period.
       This may be useful for low-bandwidth sites, or have other uses
       such as coping with annoying iptables --limit options.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a design flaw in the nmap version of `ncat` that is used in RHEL7.  I am looking at the source code of version 7.70 (RHEL7 is 7.50, Fedora 28 is 7.60 and I don't think this aspect of the code will have changed much between that and 7.70).

In `ncat_connect.c` I can see code to:

- exit after EOF on stdin in `--send-only` mode,
- exit after EOF on the socket in `--recv-only` mode,

but, if in neither `--send-only` nor `--recv-only` mode, there is *nothing* in `ncat_connect.c` to handle exit when we've seen EOF on both stdin and the socket.

So we look at the lower-level code in `nsock_core.c`'s `nsock_loop` function.  This loop will quit if `ms->quit` it set (by the above-mentioned `--send-only` and `--recv-only` code) *or* if there are no `events_pending`.

But here's the bug: *the timeout counts in events_pending*.  So `nsock_loop` goes "OK, I know stdin has been EOF'd and the socket has been EOF'd, but I'm still not going to quit yet, because there's still an event pending" (the timeout), so it just sits there until the timeout fires and then *nc error-exits*, even if everything has actually worked just fine.

So I think we should submit a bug report directly to nmap (not to your distro: they are likely to say "that's upstream behaviour we are not qualified to evaluate", whereas upstream maintainers *will* be able to evaluate it): we point out that the above design effectively means `-i` is useless unless either (1) used along with `--send-only` or `--recv-only` or (2) used in a situation where `nc`'s error code is ignored.

Meanwhile, one of the following workarounds might help:

- Use `--send-only` or `--recv-only` (if appropriate to your use-case),
- Wrap the `nc` command in a `timeout` command instead of using `-i`,
- Manually install a different version of `nc`, such as GNU Netcat or the original nc-1.10—but to do this on RHEL7 or Fedora 28 you *will* need to install manually, as packages (currently) provide only `nmap-ncat`.

Comment: I went ahead and raised this issue at https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/1311

Answer (score 0):

I have started a centos7 container and could reproduce your error:

```
[root@34630a8f0b7c /]# nc 192.168.1.210 1234 < sarassa 
[root@34630a8f0b7c /]# nc -i 1 192.168.1.210 1234 < sarassa 
Ncat: Idle timeout expired (1000 ms).
```

The -i option only adds a timeout at the end of the file transfer, so it is not clear what you want to achieve with it

Comment: After successful `nc`, I should be able to view the file contents directly from the device. This only works with 32-bit systems.